# Creating a linux-based black box environment?

Tags: linux

This is a subject I've found very little on and while there are theory-based articles out there, I can't find anything with specifics. I also wasn't sure whether this should live on stack overflow or serverfault, but since most of this is probably a form of linux administration, serverfault felt the best to me.

How would I 'black box' an OS while still allowing the required services to run?

Rephrasing the details I had before just to better explain. I have a linux-based virtual machine appliance that I've deployed at multiple locations and is designed to fulfill a specific purpose, but doesn't require the user access the server OS itself; everything they need can be configured from a custom shell and web interface and now that it is deployed, there isn't a reason for anyone (even myself) to be able to access the internals of the system. After the system is deployed, it may have private data on it and copyrighted code and so for security, I want to 'black box' this environment. How would I do this?

Essentially I want to ensure that even a power user can't get into the innards of the OS, whether by command line or booting the system from a live disk (thinking encryption of some kind).

This process would be similar to that of a Dell iDRAC, HP ILO, VMware ESXi, Cisco switches where the internals of the Linux or Unix OS can't be accessed by the person the product is sold to.

Comment: Like anything else, install only what you need.

Comment: As you mentioned a common term nowadays is a virtual appliance and quick search yields quite a bit of documentation on creating those. If you don't know where to start from scratch, create one yourself with the existing tooling and pick it apart.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Guess I didn't explain it properly. Editing my question to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: @HBruijn Tools-wise, is there anything out there that is open source or free? And would such a tool help with the actual lockdown of the VM to avoid external changes and access to things like code or database from outside the VM's OS environment?

Comment: You need to remember that Linux is copyrighted too, and if you are not carefull then your lockdown approach could lead to a violation. As far as I can tell, a question about the software license questions would be suitable for the [opensource.stackexchange.com](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/tour).